# How to use multiple jobs during configuration?

Tags: autotools

I'm working on a script to build Git from sources on Solaris. Git has about 12 dependencies, and most of them are Autotools based. The script takes longer than it should to execute because the checking performed by Autotools happens on a single thread. (Its especially painful during testing as the same steps are repeatedly performed).

I found some reading on the subject, like [Parallel Building Tricks](https://autotools.io/automake/parallel.html), but it does not discuss multiple jobs during configure. And trying the obvious does not work as expected:

```
$ ./configure -j 4
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-j'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

How do I tell Autotools and `./configure` to use multiple jobs to perform its checking (similar to `make -j 8`)?

Comment: You could try asking all the configure scripts to use the same cache file, by passing an appropriate `--cache-file` option to them.  That doesn't make them run in parallel, but it probably does speed up the configuration by avoiding duplicative tests.

Comment: Alternatively, you should be able to use whatever multiprocessing facilities are available in the main build script's language to run the various `configure` jobs via separate, parallel processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Sorry this is not a satisfying answer, but `configure` is just a shell script. There's no way to tell shell scripts to execute in parallel like that.